# Rabbinically speaking, does honoring a Mitzvah in year 5777 matter more than honoring a Mitzvah during year 1?

Tags: mitzvah, sin, modern-times

> "A person who honors a Mitzvah now, they will receive a greater grace and reward in the world to come than if they were honoring the same Mitzvah during the time of revelation.

The above statement was spoken by someone at Shul but they were unable to find me a citation for the point.

The conversation came up at a Torah study regarding the modern hardships of being a Jew. Both politically and in an age of science and doubt regarding how it is harder to maintain the Mitzvot than it has been previously.

Someone then stated that their Rabbi talked about the burden being an **amplifier** for Mitzvot. They were basically saying that because Mitzvot is being done during an age where it is harder to be a pious Jew, that there is greater reward for being a pious Jew.

The logic being that it's extremely easy to be a Jew during the time of the Torah being given or during a time of miracles.

**Why?** You were amongst those who took part in the revelation. Therefore, it isn't a matter of belief as you experienced it yourself. With every coming generation after the fact, the burden of belief becomes heavier and heavier and thus the reward for being pious is greater.

Could someone cite me exactly where this idea comes from?

Comment: Seems like a subset of the end of Avot ch. 5: According to the pain is reward:
 לפום צערא אגרא

Comment: Most Jews live under friendly governments with freedom of religion protected by law and in generally better financial situations. In what way is this not the easiest time to be a Jew in recent history?

Comment: How goes life inside that bubble?

https://www.thejc.com/news/world/don-t-stop-wearing-your-kippot-french-chief-rabbi-tells-marseille-jews-1.57402

http://www.jpost.com/Diaspora/Report-Attackers-saw-off-Jewish-mans-finger-beat-his-brother-near-Paris-482485

https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/europe/netherlands-bans-export-of-kosher-and-halal-meat-to-minimise-negative-effects-on-animal-welfare-a6881406.html

http://www.telegraph.co.uk/men/health/should-religious-circumcision-be-banned/

https://www.theguardian.com/society/2014/aug/07/antisemitism-rise-europe-worst-since-nazis